# list all the groups to which a user belongs. Using macOS and CentOS

Tags: macos, user-accounts, centos-7, user-groups

This is may question.

I want to know the groups of some user.

`$dscl . list /groups` **filterByUSer** `theFindUser` is it possible?

Comment: `groups [user]`?

Comment: as mentioned below, for current user: `groups $(whoami)` and for any user `groups user_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for active user:

```
groups $(whoami)
```

for any user:

```
groups [user_name]
```

e.g:

```
groups lukas
```